# backend not being reset by matplotlibrc.py

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, backend

I'm having trouble getting matplotlib plots to appear in front of my other windows - this is apparently a macosx backend problem. However, after making the following changes in ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc.py:

```
#backend      : macosx
backend : TkAgg
```

I run this command in python

```
import matplotlib            
print matplotlib.rcParams['backend']
```

and it returns:

```
MacOSX
[Finished in 4.1s]
```

What's going wrong?  Or rather, how do I get plots to appear in front of other windows?

Other information:

osx 10.9 (mavericks)
python --version  -> Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)
using sublime text 3, build 3083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) the rc file has no `.py` extension:

> - On Linux, it looks in `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` [...]
> - On other platforms, it looks in `.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`.

In fact it does not have python syntax but rather uses a yaml-like dictionary structure. So it is likely that matplotlib does not use your  file at all.

You can use this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

to figure out which configuration file matplotlib uses (and by that confirm that matplotlib acutally reads the file that you want to be read).

Comment: Config file is being read after removing the .py extension.  I still "cmd tab" to get to the image, but at least they're not hiding now.   Thanks!

Comment: As per your window focus problem, this seems to be relevant: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/665
Maybe updateing matplotlib will help

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was putting the following in the top of your module where you want to use `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Comment: Well, I guess I'd really like a more permanent solution; I don't understand why altering matplotlibrc.py isn't changing the backend...